# ng-change is only working for backspace and first entry

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<input type="email" ng-keypress="testFunc()" ng-model="text"
    id="femail" class="form-control margin" name="femail"
    placeholder="Email*"/>
<p style="color: red;">The input field has changed {{count}} times.</p>
```

JS

```
$scope.count = 0;
$scope.testFunc = function() {
    $scope.count++;
};
```

---

HTML

```
<input type="email" ng-change="testFunc()" ng-model="text"
       id="femail" class="form-control margin" name="femail"
       placeholder="Email*"/> 
<p style="color: red;">The input field has changed {{count}} times.</p>
```

JS

```
$scope.count = 0;
$scope.testFunc = function() {
    $scope.count++;
};
```

If I input : "abc". Result should be : 3 but I'm getting : 0 if i delete using backspack I'm getting: 1 I should get count++ on each input which i'm not getting. I'm trying this example:

> https://w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-change

in my code. Thank you

**Clarification:**
In the above provided *w3school* example and my code difference was that I was using

```
<input type="email">
```

and w3 was using

```
<input type="text">
```

So for "text input" each button press was considered as a change but in my case each change occurs when the email is changed or it has some different functionality for ng-change with

```
"input type="email".
```

So I got the counting right now by taking

```
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: <input type="email" ng-keypress="testFunc()" ng-model="text" id="femail" class="form-control margin" name="femail" placeholder="Email*"/>

<p style="color: red;">The input field has changed {{count}} times.</p>

JS

$scope.count = 0;
$scope.testFunc = function() {
 $scope.count++;
};

Comment: Please add some more description as well as JS and HTML code for better understanding. Please elaborate your question as well.

Comment: I'm new to stack so unable to post things properly. Anyway I'll try:
I'm applying ng-change="testFunc"
in JS
but the counter is not working on any change/input
it is working only for backspace button.

Comment: HTML

<input type="email" ng-change="testFunc()" ng-model="text" id="femail" class="form-control margin" name="femail" placeholder="Email*"/>
<p style="color: red;">The input field has changed {{count}} times.</p>

JS

$scope.count = 0;
$scope.testFunc = function() {
 $scope.count++;
};

If I input : "abc".
Result should be : 3
but I'm getting : 0
if i delete using backspack I'm getting: 1

I should get count++ on each input which i'm not getting.
I'm trying this example:
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-change
in my code.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just copy/pasted the example from W3(you provided) to test.txt file and renamed it test.html and run in Firefox. All worked fine. I did not have to edit anything. Try what I did first then you will know if it a typo or anything else. But the code is working correctly.

Comment: I got my answer. W3 is having input type="text" but I was using type="email"

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<input type="text" />
```

This is much better solution for your counter to work on.
If you want a counter use **type="text" not "email"**. Browser treat both of them differently.